# PHP Read csv data without first line

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I want to store csv columns data into array
I have did this so far.

```
$csvfile = file('testfile.csv');
$csvData = [];
foreach ($csvfile as $key => $line) {
        $csvData[] = str_getcsv($line);
}
```

This works fine but the first line also include in array
I want to skip first line

Answer (score 3):

Remove the first element of the array with `array_shift()`.

```
$csvfile = file('testfile.csv');
array_shift($csvfile);
$csvData = array_map('str_getcsv', $csvfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can do like this

```
$csvfile = file('testfile.csv');
unset($csvfile[0]);
$csvData = [];
foreach ($csvfile as $key => $line) {
    $csvData[] = str_getcsv($line);
}
```

Comment: before you `unset`, it's better to check whether the first line exists.